# What are the things to do get large amount of merits?

Tags: theravada, karma, merit

I'm new to this forum.

What are the most merit receiving things in Buddhism?

I already know donating or charity is a good way to earn much merits.

What are the other ways to earn merits?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll find some good answers to your question already, in the topic that I linked to above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very important question. Accumulating merit.
If you can undo all your past wrong doings then that will accrue merit.
For example if you have lied in the past and now you have taken an oath to never lie again that brings merit.
If you have collected money by wrongful means and now if you decide to donate all your money then that brings merit.
If you have hurt someone and now you decide to help him by applying balm to his wounds both metaphorically and literally then that brings merit.
If you have chosen to be punished for your past misdeeds then that brings merit.
If you have chosen to self sacrifice for the benefit of mankind then that brings merit.
If you have decided to deeply love the ugliest creature on the planet then that brings merit.
If you have decided to look at all beings with deep love then that brings merit.
If you have decided to fulfil wishes of others then that brings merit.
If you have decided to surrender to Buddha or any other equally compassionate being then that brings merit.
If you have to decided to make others happy then that brings merit.
If you have decided to provide solutions to entangled beings then that brings merit.
If you have decided to face every situation with courage then that brings merit.
If you have chosen to follow the path of Truth then that brings merit.
If you have chosen to maintain integrity then that brings merit.